# Waiting on two synchronization objects

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task

I have a worker thread that uses AutoResetEvent to determine if a queue has been modified and a CancellationToken to determine if it has been cancelled.

```
ConcurrentQueue queue = new ConcurrentQueue<MyClass>();

static private void Worker()
{
    while (true) 
    {
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            MyClass item;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
            {
                item.DoWork();
            }
        }
        autoResetEvent.WaitOne(1000);  //Wait for item to be added to queue
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();  //Check if cancelled
    }
}
```

The issue with the above is that the call to `WaitOne()` will continue to block even if the cancellation token has been signaled. In this case I have a timeout of 1 second, so the main thread will end up waiting up to one second before the task tries to finish up and exit.

Is there a way to rewrite this so that signalling the cancellation token will allow the worker thread to push through the `WaitOne()` call so it can exit?

Comment: Use BlockingCollection, not ConcurrentQueue, if you want to have a method to get a value that blocks until a value is added.  No sense writing the class yourself.

Comment: Could you possibly convert to a `new SemaphoreSlim(1,1)` and then use the `Wait(int32, CancellationToken)` instead? (assuming it fits your needs and that a BlockingCollection isn't more suitable)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`WaitHandle.WaitAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189983(v=vs.110).aspx) static method:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { autoResetEvent, cancellationToken.WaitHandle }, 1000);
```

However, there is a downside to accessing [`CancellationToken.WaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Accessing this property causes a WaitHandle to be instantiated. It is preferable to only use this property when necessary, and to then dispose the associated CancellationTokenSource instance at the earliest opportunity (disposing the source will dispose of this allocated handle). The handle should not be closed or disposed directly.